# ODE solver, fixed step width vs. adaptive step width

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Assume a matrix valued ode problem:
$$
My'+Sy=f
$$
from a FEM method, which you want to solve with a numerical ode solver (e.g. Runge Kutta, Euler). 
In our case we use the backwards Euler scheme.

We get an iteration that looks like this:
$$
(M+\Delta t S)y_{n+1}=My_n+\Delta t f(t_{n+1})
$$
Then one can choose a adaptive step width or fixed time steps. In the fixed stepwidth case one can calculate an LU-decomposition and use it for all subsequent steps, while in an adaptive method a new LU decomposition is needed for every time step. Isn't the fixed method way cheaper, especially for large problems with millions of unknowns? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: What if you want to take increasingly larger step sizes where for example your problem is very sensitive in the beginning but then the solution becomes steady?

Comment: yes,that's what I am asking about. I am aware of that different stepwidths are useful for exactly this case, because not the same accuracy is needed everywhere, but still, I think I can run a lot more steps with a fixed step size, than calculating a new LU every time. Is there some "rule of thumb" which says e.g. as soon, as one would carry out 100 steps with the fixed step width, but only one is needed, then switch step size. Something that sets this into relation.

Comment: I think you may need a problem by problem analysis. For example what if my above example now has multiple regions where small timesteps are needed. Surely some simple problems a fixed step may be much more efficient , but I can think we can extend this 'sensitive region' argument to conclude that really only adaptive steps suffice in some cases. Im not sure I could say where the balance of efficiency lies apriori.

Comment: If you can formulate things so that your LU decomposition can be updated (see e.g. [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/02331939208843741) or [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1377612.1377615)), you might be able to do the adaptive stepping more cheaply.